# Google apps script ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() always returns the wrong URL

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

According to the documentation, this method should return the URL of the web app:

*"Returns the URL of the web app, if it has been deployed; otherwise returns null. If you are running the development mode web app, this returns the development mode url."*

We have a Google Calendar add-on in which we have custom settings page (html) delivered to the clients using `HtmlService` and I have no idea how `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()` works with versioned deployments.

Here's an interesting scenario:

On a fresh Google Script project, we deployed from manifest file (NOT webapp, although we have the "webapp" part on the manifest)

1. First versioned deployment from manifest:

   `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()` correctly returns https://script.google.com/a/gong.io/macros/s/AKfycbzR21YpWNakFEisFcW1zo-tArveQ5nXj_gTRYLF4OZWkMf_Gun8Q3I2WZncfLSbjKEr/exec

   Versioned Deployment ID: `AKfycbzR21YpWNakFEisFcW1zo-tArveQ5nXj_gTRYLF4OZWkMf_Gun8Q3I2WZncfLSbjKEr`
2. Made some changes, created a new versioned deployment

   `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()` correctly returns https://script.google.com/a/gong.io/macros/s/AKfycbxXBdBXAV7olI0NGe-uS0_4FEFZPPNXLVHml6NNNW9zYf1fLOqfLhLYsaz6FTmjduIq/exec

   Versioned Deployment ID: `AKfycbxXBdBXAV7olI0NGe-uS0_4FEFZPPNXLVHml6NNNW9zYf1fLOqfLhLYsaz6FTmjduIq`
3. We've deployed the script through **Publish->Deploy as web app...** Probably done this mistakenly on our production script

   Web app URL is https://script.google.com/a/gong.io/macros/s/AKfycbzv1gX4eim1CzTjnFc4sFNvLMw9mXCfOv4laDu-_9AKefk5jXg/exec
4. Another round of code changes to the script. This time we deployed from manifest:

   `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()` **incorrectly** returns https://script.google.com/a/gong.io/macros/s/AKfycbzv1gX4eim1CzTjnFc4sFNvLMw9mXCfOv4laDu-_9AKefk5jXg/exec

   Versioned Deployment ID: `AKfycbx29Pcs8_cpEkodrfWGklz8t_OAs87OBSEtxLMkStrya64wUV4M2ePW_tNTTWlq0_T1`

Notice that this time - we got the webapp deployment ID - not the versioned deployment id.

From here on, no matter what I've tried - I will ALWAYS get https://script.google.com/a/gong.io/macros/s/AKfycbzv1gX4eim1CzTjnFc4sFNvLMw9mXCfOv4laDu-_9AKefk5jXg/exec no matter what we do.

1. Deleted all versioned deployments and created a new one
2. Disabled web app

[image]

As of now, everything I do ends up in `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()` returning this URL.

How can I reset it and get `getUrl()` to return the versioned deployment ID rather than a non-existing webapp deployment ID?

edit: typos

Comment: I cannot reproduce this same behaviour. `getUrl()` returns the `/dev` URL if I have deployed a new version from manifest but haven't deployed the webapp via `Publish > Deploy as web app...`. Could you please share the code related to the manifest file, in case I'm missing something? Also, when publishing as `Deploy as web app...`, the following message appears: `A new link will be given when you click Update. The current link will continue to work`. So it seems that when the web app is deployed this way, a new URL is generated that overrides the one created from manifest, but both work.

Comment: Considering all this, what are you using the URL for? If I may ask, why is the one created via `Deploy as web app...` not appropriate, and you want the ones corresponding to the versions deployed from manifest?

Comment: We are hosting a couple of HTMLs for the add-on settings and wouldn't want to bother with manually updating URLs in our calendar add-on.

Comment: For me getUrl() returned the right version. This was tested on the actual settings URL on Google calendar (as opposed to executing the function from the editor - where indeed it's the /dev URL).
So what exactly is `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()` is returning? If I have multiple versions deployed with `Publish > Deploy as web app...`?

Comment: Better to create a issue in the issuetracker. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Answer (score 7):

#### This might to be a bug.

This issue was reported in Issue Tracker (I'm guessing you did it), and now it got forwarded internally. Posting this here to give it more visibility:

- [ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() doesn't work for versioned deployments](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170799249)

To anyone affected by this, please click the top-left star.

Comment: Only took me about 1 month to get to this point where this is acknowledged as a bug. Just came here to post exactly your answer :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170799249#comment30 (my own comment)

> Few days ago Google make it possible to create and assign a version for an existing deployment. See [Release Notes 2021-03-15](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases#march_2021)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 2022-09-05 :**

This is not wroking anymore since the old version of editor is now closed !

**OBSOLETE :**

I get the same issue.
I fix it by switching to old version of the editor, and publish the app using the old editor version.

That's worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed, it's a bug in the new version of the editor. Changing to the old version of the editor and publishing the web app fixed the issue for me.

Usually, the URL for every release/publish of your script stays the same. But with the new editor it appears that the publishing URL is changed, whereas the `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()` is returning the "old" URL.

But even more weird is the fact that the publishing of the "Test Web App" version seems to work fine, just the deployed version doesn't reflect the changes?