# GetURL returns wrong URL

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I have a Google App Script program that has a number of HTML pages.  To generate the URL's for links to individual pages, I use this function on the server code:

```
function getScriptUrl() {
    var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();      
    return url;
}
```

to return a URL that I could then embed like this, on the client side:

```
<?var myURL = getScriptUrl();?><a class="btn btn-success" href='<?=myURL?>?page=CreateNew'>My Button/a>
```

This always returned the URL of the app.  So, if am testing in the Dev version, it returns the Dev URL, if I am in the Exe version, it returns the Exe URL.  But, now, if I am in the Dev version, it returns the Exe URL.  This was never an issue in the past but started today.  Does anyone know why this is happening or a better way to generate the URL to create links between pages?

**EDIT:**
I have tried to republish the app (in Legacy Editor and the New Editor), log out of G Suite account, clear my cache but these attempts did not work to address the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicates [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64338438/1595451), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58843993/1595451)

Comment: i've tried republishing, logging out, clearing cache.  None of the suggested solutions seem to work

Comment: Please add that to the question

Comment: Updated as requested.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should a Google part issue, I use the same logic to auto direct to prod and test page. It works fine in the passed few month. But it can't work from last week.

Answer (score 0):

I too have this problem.  Until recently I had this code to help me distinguish whether I was testing the development version or the deployed version.  It worked for months.

```
const url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
if (url.endsWith('dev')) {
  // more code here
}
```

Now getUrl() will always return the exec url.

(I know this isn't an answer, but I am a first time poster and do not have enough points to "Add a comment" and I don't want to ask a duplicate question)